# tabbar iOS app using jquery mobile and html5

Tags: jquery, android, ios, html, jquery-mobile

Is there a best way to create a iOS tabbar app only using HTML5 (and jquery mobile for ajax and other things like that) ?
I saw a lot of frameworks around there but I'm more looking for tutos where once can understand what's behind the scene.

Thanks a lot,

Regards,

Luc

Comment: What's tabbar? If you want standalone application on ios or android see phonegap

Comment: Hello, I mean tabbar like the one used in an iphone app.

Comment: Please describe or post an image, I don't rent an iphone. (disclaimer: `rent` as in pay and not be able to use in whatever way you want without asking permission, as oposed to `own`.)

Comment: @naugtur, I meant tab bar like in the following pict: http://mobiputing.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/google-latitude-ios.jpg. The tab bar is the menu at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Yes, It's possible and it's there in jquerymobile.com docs. Please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

check out http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html